# Check if multiple lines exist in text file

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement, logic, perl-module

Using Perl I would like to check if the two lines highlighted below exist in a text file . Each line is preceded by a tab.

```
CF=CFU-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES;
CF=CFB-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES;
***CF=CFU-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES;***
CF=CFNRY-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES;
CF=CFNRC-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES;
***CF=CFB-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES;***
CF=CFD-TS10-REG-9124445544-YES-YES;
```

I am using the following if statement but it is not matched

```
if (/\t*CF=(CFU-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/  && /\t*CF=(CFB-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/)
{       
 say "this case is found here .....";
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

*Edited*
This is the program I wrote :-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $HSSIN='D:\testproject\HSS-export-test-run-small.txt';
my $ofile = 'D:\testproject\HSS-output.txt';
open (INFILE, $HSSIN) or die "Can't open input file";
open (OUTFILE,"> $ofile" ) or die "Cant open file"; 
my $add;
my $MSISDN;

my $line; 


 sub callForwardingsCF()

    {

 if (/\t*CF=(CFU-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/  && /\t*CF=(CFB-TS10-ACT-(NONE|+\d+))/)

    {

   say "this case is found here .....";


    } 

    } # end sub callForwardingsCFD



while (<INFILE>) 
{
    if (/<SUBEND/)  
    {
        say "SUBEND found";
        #$line = $1 if /^\s*MSISDN=(\d+);/;
        print OUTFILE "processSingle UpdateCommand GSUB MKEY $line";
        print OUTFILE "\n";

    }

    if ($_ =~ /^\t*MSISDN=(\d+);/) 
    {   #find MSISDN in file global search

     say "STARTER MSISDN is $1";  
     $MSISDN = $1;  
     $add = $1;     
     $line = "$1";   #group 1 

    }  

callForwardingsCF();  #callForwardings 

}
```

close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;

Example of a record in the input file

```
<BEGINFILE>
<SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=232191400029053;
    MSISDN=4369050064401;
    DEFCALL=TS11;
    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
    CAT=COMMON;
    TBS=TS11&TS12&TS21&TS22;
    VLRLIST=10;
    SGSNLIST=10;
    SMDP=MSC;
    CB=BAOC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BOIC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BOICEXHC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BICROAM-ALL-PROV;
    CW=CW-ALL-PROV;
    CF=CFU-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFB-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFU-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFNRY-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFNRC-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFB-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFD-TS10-REG-91436903000-YES-YES-25-YES-65535-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-YES-YES-YES-YES-NO;
    TCSISTATE=YES;
    OCSISTATE=YES;
    CONTROL=SUB;
    WPA=0;
    GS=HOLD&MPTY&ECT&CLIR&CLIP;
    CLIRES=TEMPALLOW;
    CLIPOC=NO;
    OCSI=10;
    CFSMS=ACT-10-914366488325207-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO;
    ARD=PROV;
    SUBRES=ALLPLMN;
    IST_ALERT_TIMER=120;
    IST_ALERT_RESPONSE=2;
    SUB_AGE=0;
    MIMSI=240076400029053-ONELIVE-2-2-1-0-0;
    MIMSI=232191400029053-ONELIVE-1-1-1-0-0;
    SID=2805158185721065;
    MCSISTATE=YES;
    CLRBSG=CLIP-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    UPLCSLCK=NO;
    UPLPSLCK=NO;
    DEFOFAID=10;
    EPS_PROFILE_ID=1;
    TGPPAMBRMAXUL=50000000;
    TGPPAMBRMAXDL=150000000;
    ARD_EXT=NULL-NULL-NULL-N3GPPNOTALLOWED;
    FRAUDTPL_ID=10;
    HLR_INDEX=1;
    LTEAUTOPROV=NO;
    PSSER=1-1-10-1-NONE-DYNAMIC-00000000;
    EPSSER=1-10-10-1-NONE-DYNAMIC-00000000-1;
    MPS=NO;
<SUBEND
```

Thanks, 
Graham

Comment: I don't know; what *are* you doing wrong? We have no idea what you're doing so we can't say what is *wrong*. What is happening that shouldn't happen? We can't really help you without seeing what you've written. You reveal below that you are *"slurping an input file using a `while` loop"*. That's a start, but it should be in your question, not a comment. And *why* are you slurping the whole thing?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1211742

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the program a simple test to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are reading the file linewise. "Slurping" means reading the file in one go. This way your check can never match, as you expect each line to contain only one of your criteria.

Comment: in the data you posted, the lines are not preceded by tabs (\t+). they are preceded by multiple spaces (\s+).

Answer (score 1):

Per default regexes match linewise.

So **if** you were trying to match an input that contains multiple lines, you would have to use one of the modifiers that allows the regex to match the entire string.

See the [the perl regex documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - the chapter "Modifiers".

Then you should add the `s` modifiler and change your if statement to:

```
if ( /\t*CF=(CFB-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/s &&
     /\t*CF=(CFU-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/s ) {
   say "found";
}
```

If you read linewise you will never have both of your regexes match for the same line, so you would need to do your regexes seperately as already suggested by the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#$/ = ""; #without paragraph mode

open my $file, '<', 'data_file';
binmode $file; 

while(<$file>){
        print $_  if ( $_ =~ /\s+CF=CFU-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-\d+-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;/ || 
                       $_ =~ /\s+CF=CFB-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-\d+-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;/  );
    }
```

EDIT:

OR, you can do it in paragraph mode if conditions allow it.

```
$/ = ""; 

open my $file, '<', 'data_file';
binmode $file;

while(<$file>){
    (undef, $first) = split (/\s+(CF=CFU-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-\d+-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;)/, $_);
    (undef, $second) = split(/\s+(CF=CFB-TS10-ACT-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-\d+-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;)/, $_ );
     print $first . "\n" . $second;
}
```

Code is tested and seems to work fine with supplied data.

Also, those are not tabs "\t" ... those are spaces "\s+" preceding those lines. Best thing is to learn your data set before you try to parse it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Typically perl processes file "line by line".
Try something like sample script below:

```
my($line1,$line2);
while(<STDIN>) {
  $line1=$_ if /\t*CF=(CFU-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/
  $line2=$_ if /\t*CF=(CFB-TS10-ACT-(NONE|\d+))/
  if( $line1 and $line2 ) {  
    say "this case is found here .....";
    last; # skip processing remaning lines
  }
}
```

Alternatively you may "slurp" whole file into one scalar variable.

Comment: This code would be part of a larger program. I am slurping an input file using a while loop. The file contains multiple records. Each record starts with <SUBBEGIN followed by lines which I parse and ends with <SUBEND. The main while loop opens the input file checks each line of the file. So I am not sure how to formulate the while loop you suggest in this context?

Comment: there is no reason to slurp the entire file and then read it. just read the file line by line or in paragraph mode. see my answer for details